# save worksheet as new workbook to a specific folder

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a workbook that I work on and save the current worksheet as a new workbook to send it to someone. I have done it until it prompts me with SaveAs Dialog Box but I want it to save it into a specific folder and with the name I specified and a range value. when I run it, it saves it under Windows default download folder and name as "False". Please help.

Also, when I copy the worksheet to a new workbook, when I open the new workbook, it prompt me with a dialog box that says "this workbook contains link  blah blah" and ask me to update... is it possible to code in a way that when I save as a new workbook, there is no link to the original work book? Please help me !!

```
Sub Save_As_Workbook()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbnew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filename As String
Dim userprofile As String

userprofile = Environ$("userprofile")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PL")
Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
wb.Activate

ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value



wbnew.SaveAs filename = userprofile & "\Dropbox\PL Folder\"outshipment" & _
"PO" & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Value


wbnew.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this all work? I think you need instead `wbnew.SaveAs filename:= userprofile & "\Dropbox\PL Folder\outshipment" & _
"PO" & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Value`, no? (You may need an additional `\`, I'm not sure though since I don't know the true path)

Comment: I think you may to add "Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False" into your new workbook under Sub Workbook_Open() module...

Comment: for the save as, I think you may need to specify the directory (for example C:\, L:\ etc.) before the userprofile